# Retrieve (get) current weather data from html table with php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I would like to get current weather data from html table from the other site. Web page from which i would like to get the current (refresh every hour) information about river, flow and other information: http://www.arso.gov.si/vode/podatki/stanje_voda_samodejne.html.

The question is how can i retrieve data for all columns (data about the river) but not for all rows (rivers) example river Mura, Drava, Sora.

I would like to display data with php or javascript on table on my site. Please help!

Comment: you can find scrapper code for that purpose

Answer (score 0):

**get data from url**

This will give you html of given page.

```
$content = file_get_contents('you url here');
$this->html =  $content;
$this->process();
function process(){

// Your html extraction code here
}
```

**Note**

Webscrping is use for scrap a public data from website.Its depend on policy of website.

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-legality-of-web-scraping

Comment: I think i made a mistake.........
  $content = file_get_contents('http://www.arso.gov.si/vode/podatki/stanje_voda_samodejne.html');
$this->html =  $content;
$this->process();
function process(){

  print "<tr> <td>";
        echo $content[0]; 
        

}

Comment: you need to extract it your self